# Travelling to Non-EU countries while Blue card in application

Tags: germany, work-permit

I am from India, presently in Germany with a valid residence permit (as a student) which will expire in next couple of months. I am going to apply for blue card in next couple of days based on my job contract. My question is am I allowed to travel to India and come back based on validity of my residence permit while my blue card is in process or based on the note I'll get after applying for blue card in next couple of days. Thanks in advance